# 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade ignores NetworkManager.conf

Tags: networking, upgrade, network-manager, 16.04, dns

The machine in question was a straight from dvd install of 14.04 (upgraded to date before upgrade to 16.04 on 27-APR-16), with static ip, bind9 and registered domain. `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` edited to reflect static ip, namesevers, search. `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` was edited `#dns_dnsmasq` allowing information from `/etc/dhcp/dhclienet.conf` to used for `/etc/resolv.conf`.

After upgrade `/etc/resovl.conf` reads `nameserver 127.0.0.1`. Using the new Network Icon this desired `/etc/resovl.conf` can be obtained, but this must be redone every time a connection is made, unlike previously once all properly edited it worked done. `cat /etc/resolv.conf` returned the desired: `nameserver 1xx.2xx.1xx.5x` (3 all together) and search Home domain.name.

What need to be done to have it work as before?

Answer (score 0):

After diligent research found the useful bit:

apt-get remove --purge dnsmasq

```
 resolvconf -u

 service network-manager restart
```

and all was as before the upgrade.